# MSVC instantiates class template in constexpr-if statement which shouldn't be instantiated

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have a piece of code that compiles with GCC and Clang, but not with MSVC and I can't figure out why. The problem is that MSVC instantiates a class template in the `constexpr-if` statement which GCC and Clang do not instantiate.

I boiled it down as good as I can, please bear with me if the boiled down example doesn't make much sense.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
protected:
    virtual ~Foo(){}
};

template <typename E>
struct Bar : public Foo
{

    Bar(E const& e) : value(e) {}

    void foo() override final {
        bool x = std::is_pointer_v<E>;
    }

    E value;
};

template <typename T>
void some_function(){

    auto inner_lambda = []() {
        if constexpr (!std::is_abstract_v<T>) 
        {
            // why does MSVC instantiate this template?
            Bar<T> u;
        }
    };
};

class Base {
public:
    virtual void fun() = 0;
protected:
    virtual ~Base(){}    
};

int main()
{
    some_function<Base>();
    return 0;
}
```

### Compiler error

```
<source>(22): error C2282: 'Bar<T>::~Bar' cannot override 'Foo::~Foo'
        with
        [
            T=Base
        ]
<source>(17): note: while compiling class template member function 'void Bar<T>::foo(void)'
        with
        [
            T=Base
        ]
<source>(31): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Bar<T>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=Base
        ]
<source>(45): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void some_function<Base>(void)' being compiled
Compiler returned: 2
```

Interestingly, I couldn't boil down the example much further:

- Making `foo` a non-virtual member function of `Bar` makes MSVC compile the code
- Removing the call to `std::is_pointer_v<E>` in `foo` makes MSVC compile the code
- Not nesting the `if constexpr` in the inner lambda `inner_lambda` of `some_function` makes MSVC compile the code.
- Making the virtual destructor of `Base` public makes MSVC compile the code.

All of these seem unrelated to me, so this smells a lot like a compiler bug. Am I wrong?

Here is a [Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/an8sx7r8f)

Comment: All compilers compile your program. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nYr8KeWbj). **Use the latest version of the compilers.**

Comment: apparently only `/std:c++17` on lasted `msvc` produce error (and `c++20` on `v19.31`)

Comment: @MooingDuck That is why I said use the latest version. Also even with msvc v19.33 c++20 the program works.[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h1o876eW7)

Comment: Ah great! Good to know! So a compiler bug in MSVC<19.33 then? I'd still be interested in what goes wrong...

Comment: @joergbrech There is no point in submitting a bug as it(whatever the bug was) has already been fixed. If we do, they will just close it as it has already been fixed.

Comment: @Jason Liam Sure, I'd still be curiuous to see the relevant bug report. The bug seems so strange to me that I can't put my finger on what goes wrong.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/fEdd8vWv9 As a quick double-check, `std::is_abstract_v<T>` is true on both the broken and working compilers.

Comment: @joergbrech Here is the bug report: [MSVC rejects valid program involving constexpr if](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-rejects-valid-program-involving-con/10190952)

Answer (score 1):

The program is well-formed. Note that the program is accepted by msvc if you either change to c++20 from msvc v19.32 onwards or if we use latest version of msvc with c++17.

> this smells a lot like a compiler bug. Am I wrong?

Yes, it is a msvc bug that has been fixed with the latest version. Here is the corresponding bug report:

[MSVC rejects valid program involving constexpr if](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-rejects-valid-program-involving-con/10190952)

Comment: Thanks! This still doesn't explain what the problem is, but maybe we will get an anwer there.

Comment: @joergbrech : You will never get that sort of feedback about compiler issues on DevCommunity. (Stdlib issues, occasionally.) Don't get your hopes up.